# Is it possible to add a form-feed to an asp.net panel?

Tags: c#

I want to add a form-feed to my panel after each Item that I print so that I can have each Item print on its own page.

Is that even possible to do?

For example I can add a line-break to my panel but not sure how to add a form-feed.

Example:

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [page-break-after css style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after):

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br style='page-break-after:always;' />"));
```

And watch for the newer [break-after css style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after) to replace it (not well supported yet):

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br style='break-after:page;' />"));
```

Note that these apply to a box, so using a `<br/>` may not be the best choice. An `<hr/>` might work better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to get the desired behaviour.

There are [`page-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) css attributes that instruct the browser to insert page breaks before or after an html element.

Ideally, they should not impact the look of the page when displayed in a browser, so you should use media queries, something [like](http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks):

```
@media all {
  .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
  .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

Comment: Browsers already ignore page breaks for screen, so this isn't currently necessary (except perhaps the display:none vs all). However, the new `break-after` also handles column breaks, which might impact browser screens, so it's good to start thinking in these terms.

Answer (score -1):

The [form feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed) character is `"\f"`.

Note that HTML is whitespace agnostic, so browsers will render this as just a normal space character. But if you really need a form feed, that's how to do it.